# How to move from libclntsh.so.12.1 to libclntsh.so.10.1

Tags: php, oracle

I previously install Oracle Instant Client version 12 and wanna to downgrade to Oracle Instant Client version 10. And now i got error each time i want to use php artisan, this the following error :

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   '/usr/lib/php/20151012/oci8.so' - libclntsh.so.12.1: cannot open
>   shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

Why the system still load libclntsh.so.12.1 ? Of course not found cause i already uninstall that , and now what available is : libclntsh.so.10.1

Answer (score 0):

If you downgrade the Oracle Client like this, you will need to remove and reinstall (aka recompile) the OCI8 extension.